# Rank deficient matrix polynomial implies linear dependence of coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the $3 \times 3$ matrix polynomial

$$M(x)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}Ax&Bx&Cx\\1&1&1\end{array}\right)$$

where $A, B, C$ are $2 \times 2$ real matrices. Assume that $\mbox{rank} (M(x)) \leq 2$ for all $x$ in a neighborhood of zero. Then, by a direct calculation, we have that the set $\{A,B,C\}$ is linearly dependent.

Is this a manifestation of a more general phenomenon, or pure luck?

Edit: The result fails without symmetry of the matrices, and holds for $m$ symmetric matrices $A_i\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, i=1,\dots,m$. That is, $\mbox{rank}(M(x))\leq 2, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ implies $\mbox{rank}\{A_1,\dots,A_m\}\leq2$.

Comment: If $A$, $B$, $C$ are $2\times 2$ matrices, then there are six columns (at least in the top two rows). Do you mean that $A$, $B$, $C$ are $2\times 1$ matrices? Or are you taking $x$ itself to be a column of size two? Please explain what you intended.

Comment: $x$ is $2\times 1$.

Comment: It would be nice if you posted your "direct calculation".

Comment: I did it on Mathematica. $det(M(x))$ identically zero gives 3 equations on the 12 matrix entries. Solving for three variables and computing the $3\times 3$ minors of the $3\times 4$ matrix where each line correspond to one matrix entries, we get that they are all zero.

Comment: And where is the "neighborhood of zero" used?

Comment: It is not. You only need a sufficiently large number of points where the rank condition holds in order to get identically zero polynomial.

Comment: 3 equations in 12 unknowns is quite underdetermined. You got only zero solutions?

Comment: Yes. As far as I looked at the equations, all cases gave zero determinant solutions.

Comment: All cases? What if there are infinitely many? Also, why didn't you post the Mathematica code in your question?

Comment: Although there are infinitely many solutions, there are not  infinitely many cases to analyse.

Comment: How so? You have $3$ bilinear equations in $12$ unknowns. What do the minors tell you?

Comment: Well, either some unknowns are zero, or I can solve the equations in some variables. In both cases I can perform the determinant calculation symbolically and everything cancels out. The minors tell me that the matrix [a11, a12, a21, a22; b11, b12, b21, b22; c11, c12, c21, c22] has rank two, hence one line is a linear combination of the others, and the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

So for all $x$ in a neighborhood of zero, by subtracting columns we find that the 2-vectors $(B-A)x$ and $(C-A)x$ are linearly dependent, i.e. scalar multiples of each other.
Suppose $(B-A)x=\lambda(C-A)x$ and $(B-A)y=\mu(C-A)y$ for an $y$ in the same neighborhood such that $x-y$ is also in the same neighborhood. Subtracting both, we find $\lambda =\mu$ and thus $(B-A)=\lambda(C-A)$, i.e.  the set $\{A,B,C\}$ is linearly dependent.

I do not yet see how this argument can be extended *directly* to bigger matrices, like e.g. $$M(x)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}Ax&Bx&Cx&Dx\\1&1&1&1\end{array}\right)$$ with $3\times3$ matrices $A,B,C,D$ and $x\in\mathbb R^3$, but it seems to look rather straightforward.

Comment: I have a prove when all matrices are symmetric and a counter-example otherwise, which I can post if anyone is interested (it is a bit lengthy though).

Comment: Please post your counterexample!

Comment: $M(x)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}x&x&x\\-x+y& 0&y\\1&1&1\end{array}\right)$

Comment: This matrix has determinant identically zero (first line is a multiple of the third).

Comment: Your proof, as fas as I can tell, needs non-singularity of $B-A$ and $C-A$.

Comment: oops you are right. So in fact $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\-1& 1 \end{array}\right),B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0 \end{array}\right), C=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1 \end{array}\right) $ is a counterexample to your original statement. In spite of the 0's, $B$ is independent of $\{A,C\}$.